# SQL query that checks by week

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL query that checks for whether a person is active for two consecutive weeks in the year.

For example,

```
Table1:
Name | Activity | Date
Name1|Basketball| 08-08-2014
Name2|Volleyball| 08-09-2014
Name3|None      | 08-10-2014
Name1|Tennis    | 08-14-2014
```

I want to retrieve Name1 because that person has been active for two consecutive weeks in the year.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM Table1 
Where YEAR(Date) = 2014 AND 
      Activity NOT 'None' AND
```

This is where I would need the logic that checked for an activity in two consecutive weeks. A week can be described as 7 to 14 days later. I am working with MYSQL.

Comment: will there be any start range in query??? If not the you have to go with the program logic to do this!! :)

Comment: what database type (vendor) and version do you use; options for solving this differ amongst databases and even their versions, it looks like MS SQL Server, but what version?

Comment: @doniyor he is leaving it open to edit mention that after that AND is where he believes the logic needs to be.

Comment: @doniyor the last AND is where I would need the conditon of checking for two consecutive active weeks. Maybe it was a poor way of indicating that the query was not finished.

Comment: @Torrezzzz the start range would be from the beginning of the indicated year till the end of it, or until the most recent date. In the case if 2014, it would be from Jan 1st 2014 until today.

Comment: @Zali oh ok :) now I see

Comment: And I'm MySQL. I have no idea what a '08-08-2014' is!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the logic using an `exists` subquery:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.date between t.date + 7 and t.date + 14
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

I have avoided using YEAR(`Date`) in the where clause deliberately, and recommend you do too. Using functions on multiple rows of data to suit a single criteria (2014) never makes sense to me, plus it destroys the effectiveness of indexes (see "sargable" at wikipedia). Way easier to just define a filter by a date range IMHO.

I've used a correlated subquery to derive `nxt_date` which might not scale very well, but overall the performance will depend on your indexes most probably.

```
select distinct
      name
from (
      select
              t.name
            , t.Activity
            , t.`Date`
            , (
               select min(table1.`Date`) from table1 
               where t.name = table1.name 
               and table1.Activity <> 'None'
               and table1.`Date` > t.`Date`
               ) as nxt_date
      from table1 as t
      where ( t.`Date` >= '2014-01-01' and t.`Date` < '2015-01-01' )
      and t.Activity <> 'None'
      ) as sq
where datediff(sq.nxt_date, sq.`Date`) <= 14
;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbbb3/9

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is performance relevant, but I like concise queries:

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1, Table1 t2
Where t1.Name=t2.Name AND
  t1.Date >= '2014-01-01' AND t1.Date < '2015-01-01' AND
  t1.Activity <> 'None' AND
  t1.Date < t2.Date AND
  datediff(t2.Date, t1.Date) <= 14
```

I liked the hint of @user2067753 about the `YEAR(date)`.

I used the sqlfiddle of [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25161078/2075579) to check the performance using the `explain` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). It seems that avoiding sub queries as in [VACN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25160881/2075579) or mine is beneficial (see [join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbbb3/26/0) vs [sub query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbbb3/27/0))

Comment: yes, this join may work better than the correlated subquery see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16d18/1

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I suggest this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name
FROM Table1 AS t1, Table1 AS t2
WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
AND t2.Date BETWEEN t1.Date-7 AND t1.Date+7;
```

The idea is basically: you call your table twice, select the rows whose names match, and then keep only those whose second date are up to 7 days away from the first date.

Comment: @Christof R Indeed! How about getting rid of these day/month/year divisions? Like `t2.Date BETWEEN t1.Date-7 AND t1.Date+7`? Do you think it would work better?

Comment: this sounds right, however, it should maybe be `t2.Date BETWEEN t1.Date+7 AND t1.Date+14` I guess.